# how to identify whether a person is online or not

Tags: asp.net, skype

I am creating a userprofile type of thing in my site i want to show all user SKYPE status whether online or offline how to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to show their status you could add the following link the their real skype status with:

```
<img src="http://mystatus.skype.com/smallclassic/USER-SKYPE-NAME-GOES-HERE" />
```

Comment: @mac check out this link for more info: http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/ You might need to have a privacy setting set to allow anyone to see your status.